# Python bs4 not returning text from elements

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape reverb.com to get the names of different instruments. I have found the element that holds the instrument name text, but for some reason the tags return blank. I will provide my code below. Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

url = 'https://reverb.com/marketplace?query=jackson+guitars'

response = requests.get(url).text
soup = Soup(url, 'html.parser')
for item in soup.find_all('h4', class_='grid-card__title'):
    print(item.text)
```

If you go to the web site, there are many results for the search. The most I've been able to return is four results, and I usually get back an empty list. I checked, and they all appear to have that h4 with the same class. Any ideas as to why it is not returning all results? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

In line 6, you are using the requests library to get the content under the URL provided. In the next step, you should use the response of this request as input for Beautiful Soup, not the URL address. Just update this single line:

```
soup = Soup(response, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked! I knew it was a bad idea to work on things when I was tired....